# ¿Como conservar los valores de un calculo con inputs en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero calcular la ley de OHM (i = v / r) y tengo tres `<input>` y un botón con `onClick="dividir()"` para llamar a la siguiente función dentro de mi HTML:

```
function dividir() {
    v = document.getElementById("voltaje").value;
    r = document.getElementById("resistencia").value;
    i = v / r;
    document.getElementById("corriente").value = i;
};
```

La función cumple su cometido pero el valor resultado y solo aparece unos segundos y desaparece.

Código HTML:

```
<div class="container app-contenedor">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>V</label>
            <input type="text" class="app-input" id="voltaje"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>R</label>
            <input type="text" class="app-input" id="resistencia"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>I</label>
            <input type="text" class="app-input" id="corriente"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <button class="btn app-resultado app-resultado-boton" type="submit" id="calcular" onclick="dividir()">Calcular</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

¿Como puedo dejar que el resultado quede visualizado en el campo de texto? o en su lugar debería crear otro elemento que refleje el resultado de la división?

Comment: Puedes incluir el código HTML?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de tener un botón `<button>`? Por lo que mencionas parece que tienes un submit de la forma `<input type="submit">` o de la forma `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: Agregue el código del HTML de esta parte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en tu código, el problema está aquí:

```
<button class="btn app-resultado app-resultado-boton" type="submit" id="calcular" onclick="dividir()">Calcular</button>
```

Remueve el `type="submit"` del componente HTML:

```
<button class="btn app-resultado app-resultado-boton" id="calcular" onclick="dividir()">Calcular</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

por que no probar almacenar la variable en algún lugar, puede ser la cache, y después mandarla a llamar:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('clave', 'valor');
```

Guarda la información valor a la que se podrá acceder invocando a clave. Por ejemplo clave puede ser nombre y valor puede ser Francisco.

Answer (score 0):

Mi error estaba en tener un button type="submit" que estaba validando los valores, gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Comment: esta pregunta fue reportada pero creo que se podria mantener aqui porque esta antes de que la respuesta aceptada fuera publicada no me fije en eso Saludos. borrare este comentario

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer se parece a esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<SCRIPT>
function dividir() {
    v = document.getElementById("voltaje").value;
    r = document.getElementById("resistencia").value;
    i = v / r;
    document.getElementById("corriente").value = i;
};
</SCRIPT>
voltaje <input id=voltaje><br>
resistencia <input id=resistencia<br>
corriente <input id=corriente><br>>
<button onclick="dividir()">Calcular</button>
```

Ese ejemplo sencillo funciona, por lo que si te aparece unos segundos, y desaparece, tendras problemas con otro código o CSS que no has comentado.

Comment: ¿De qué forma esto es una respuesta?

Comment: Como podrá comprobar no tengo suficiente reputación para comentar respuestas ajenas, así que he usado la única herramienta disponible para poder hacer una indicación, indicación que, por cierto, aun no siendo una respuesta directa, aclaro que el código mostrado no es el problema,  indicando otras posibilidades. Por esas dos razones no comprendo el exceso de celo de su comentario.